# proper git workflow on our 2 dev setup

Tags: git, workflow, git-workflow

We have a repository and it only has one branch: **master**.

My friend and I `git clone` on **master** in our local machines. Whenever we have changes we `git commit` & `git push` on **master** and `git pull` for update.

Now, we bought a VPS to serve as our staging *(and will be production later on)* and we also setup a subdomain on our domain:

http://dev.domain.com/ **=>** `/var/www/project_dev`

http://domain.com/ **=>** `/var/www/project_prod`

Now I am confused what should I do to have a git copy on both directories. Should I create a **development branch** and we push our local changes there and that is where `/var/www/project_dev` will clone? Then the master branch is where I should clone the `/var/www/project_prod`? Can you please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using **[this workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)**.

[image: Git branching model]

Basically, you normally commit to `develop` branch. Merges into `master` indicate **stable releases**. So whenever you merge into master, have a hook pulling from the `master` branch on the staging repo to the `master` branch on the production repo.

Comment: So there will be two repo then?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia: Yes, one for the production, one for the staging. You commit to the staging, and hooks automatically `git pull` from the production.

Comment: Ok, but how do I merge from develop branch to master of staging? And pardon, it's my first time hearing that hook. Can you explain it a bit in scenario?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia: [git merge](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)?

Comment: **Git Flow** seems like un-necessary overkill for a simple 2 developer workflow that OP currently has.

Comment: @Shiva: I use it for personal projects (things I work on alone). It's very simple to set up and very helpful history-wise.

Comment: I do like it, future-proof in case our core team grows.